# Wrong regular expression for phone format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, activerecord

There is the following regular expression to describe regular expression:

```
validates :phone, format: { with: /\A(\+7|8)[0-9]{10}\z/ }
```

'89277777777' must match this expression, '+79277777777' must too. But I have got 'invalid phone' message always. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: What is `validates`, `:phone`, `:format` What it the source of the message? I don't know how that regex is involved in the process, but as far as the matching is concerned, the regex you have matches both strings.

Comment: I didn't see any problem with your regex. It must be any other issue.

Comment: @sawa if you read what the OP is asking, it does _not_ match what he's looking for.  He wants a regex that will match an 11-digit number that may (or may _not_) start with a `+`, followed by a `7` _or_ an `8`, followed by 10 digits.  Why don't you at least _try_ to help him?

Comment: @sawa Those are Ruby on Rails/ActiveRecord methods/parameters.

Comment: Donovan, the hostility is not warranted.  Part of helping someone is helping them clarify their question.  The given regular expression does indeed match the two given inputs.  I just tried it in IRB: `p=['+79277777777','89277777777'];p.map{|s|s=~ /\A(\+7|8)[0-9]{10}\z/ }` (result `[0, 0]`).  @malcoauri, could you just tell us what valid input you are giving that results in the "invalid phone" error?  Do you have another validation on the `:phone` field you aren't showing us?

Comment: The two strings in the original post are "+7" followed by 10 digits and "8" followed by 10 digits.

Comment: @DavidGrayson you're right, of course, I was a bit frustrated because I already _tried_ to help and got slapped (proverbially).  However, I think you, too, may have missed the _intent_ of the OPs question.  He's trying to match an international phone number, so _unless I'm mistaken_, it should also match `+8927777777` (which the current regex does not).  That's all I was trying to say.

Answer (score 1):

If all you want to do is a simple way to validate an international number, which may *or may not* start with a `+` followed by either a <kbd>7</kbd> or an <kbd>8</kbd>, followed by 10 more digits, then this regex should do the trick:

```
\A\+?[78]\d{10}\z
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Fu8mOd_d5KL23Ht9)

If my assumptions are incorrect, let me know in the comments and we'll work on a better solution.

*Note: don't forget to surround the regex with // -- I didn't do that here due to the use of Debuggex*